# File write attempt gives no such file or directory error

Tags: node.js

I am creating a folder if does not exist and write a file inside that. But following code gives me

```
let fs = require('fs');
let mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
let path = require('path');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {

    ................

    var dir = '/home/malintha/test';

    mkdirp(dir, function(err) {

        // path exists unless there was an error

    });

    fs.writeFile("/home/malintha/test/malintha.txt", data, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
  }
.................
```

Gives me

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/malintha/test/malintha.txt'
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/malintha/test/malintha.txt' }
```

What is the reason for this issue?

Comment: You need to write the file **after** you make the directory.  Put the `fs.writeFile` in the callback to `mkdirp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdirp` is async; you can [use `mkdirp.sync`](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp#user-content-mkdirpsyncdir-opts), write the file in the callback, or promisify things. The example on the module's GH page shows this as well:

```
mkdirp('/tmp/foo/bar/baz', function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    else console.log('pow!') // <=- Your stuff goes here.
});
```

See the `else` clause? That means its been created. You're likely writing before it's created.